# Does the Oculus Touch controllers work with the OpenVR SDK?

Tags: oculus, virtual-reality, openvr

I am currently about to write my VR game engine. I am trying to decide if I should use the Oculus SDK or the OpenVR SDK. I have looked everywhere and can't find how well the Oculus Touch controllers work with the OpenVR SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I have a project built in Unity with OpenVR for the Vive. I set up the Oculus Touch on my computer and ran the project in Unity and the Touch controllers worked without changing anything. I had to make some adjustments to get the button mapping I wanted, but in my experience having just tried this, building for both the Vive and Touch using OpenVR works just fine. I have not noticed any problems with the Touch controllers through OpenVR and in reading forums it sounds like there are no performance issues. However if you only want to target Oculus, it sounds like OpenVR will be preferable. 
I'm no expert but I hope that helps!